# How to refresh a specific div of a page in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, reload

I am making an online game using PHP and JavaScript, I have more knowledge in PHP than I do in JavaScript, though I am new in both languages, so keep that in mind.

So what I was trying to make in PHP / JavaScript and of course HTML was to refresh only the div or the area of code that I need, and I can't make the page reload every time that it gets new information or data because when the PHP is ran and done then I can't have anything else running, unless I was to use a loop though that sounds a bit sketchy and not sure if that's the method. I have tried: (PHP)

```
header("reload: 1");
```

Though that only refreshed the page, that is what I want to happen when I get data not always to be happening, so for example the program would get the information that someone is ready then it would send the client to another page as asll as the other client.

Though I would just like an explination if it is possible to only refresh a specific area when told to by example getting MySQL data.

Comment: Use ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: You have two options AJAX and Websockets. With websockets you can actively transfer data from the server to the client. If you don't have the option to install Node.js and use websockets, then you need to use AJAX and connect per a fix interval every X second to the server and check for new data.

Comment: Remember that after your PHP serves the HTML, it can't do anything again. Your PHP runes once and only once on the server. It then sends HTML to the client browser. Within that browser/HTML, you can use JavaScript to refresh the page, including after it responds to a network request.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois TS need ajax, dont confuse him by websockets. You may remember COMET, Iframe, Flex and other alternatives, but why? Ajax enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function refresh_box() 
{
    $("#myDiv").load('path your PHP file');
    setTimeout(refresh_box, 60000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   refresh_box();
});
```

this `setTimeout` call your function for every 1 minute and load content dynamically in `mydiv`.

Comment: I se no jQuery tag in the Question. Do you?